# Should Genesis 6:2 be translated, the "sons of God" or the "sons of the gods"?

Tags: hebrew, grammar

I noticed the definite art. before Elohim in this verse, which I thought was common knowledge that whenever the definite art is before Elohim, it references other spiritual entities.

Genesis 6:2 RSV

> ... the sons of God saw that the daughters of men were fair; and they took to wife such of them as they chose.

Comment: That is definitely not a rule of any sort. See Genesis 5:22.

Comment: Don't you think that this could have reference with His relationship with the hosts of Heaven (Dan.4:17; cp. Job.5:1)? How many times does it say that one talked with the LORD, and then it says it was an angel.

Comment: I think we need to see more than one scripture with the def art. that has refence to the LORD, before we come to your conclusion, right?

Comment: apparently translating the definite art. is an art, not a science.

Comment: @ThatwemaybethepraiseofHisglory—Well, frankly, you’re the one making the positive claim that “whenever the definite art is before Elohim it has refence to other spiritual entities”. I’ve provided proof that is not the case. Have you provided any proof that it is [always] the case? The burden of proof is on you to substantiate your positive claim, not on me to disprove it. Nevertheless, Gen. 5:24, Gen. 6:9, Gen. 17:18...how many more do you need?

Comment: You dont learn unless you ask question

Comment: honestly though i think your references are a little suspect, notice in the first two they are in the context of the watcher/divine counsel motif; and as far as Abraham  God was letting him know Ishmel would leave him to the regions that he would form nations from, it seems to be saying that Abraham wanted his son to live (long) in the presence of the sons of God, which area they had rule over and were appointed according to the Deuteronomy 32:8-9 world view, which Hagar seemed pretty concerned with and God  answered Her (Gen.21:14-18)

Comment: The word walked is departed with Enoch, could be saying he departed from the gods, so God took him. Do you know any resources where I can trace out ever occurrence of the definite art. Before God because I can't figure out how to find all of them besides a manual seach

Answer (score 1):

The definite article does indicate that the following noun (assuming it is a noun, as the article can sometimes precede an adjective as well), is not being used as a name, and is being made "definite" grammatically by the article.

Names are automatically definite *without* an article, and are not even supposed to have an article attached to them.  There is debate among scholars with respect to "elohim" as to whether it should sometimes (or even always) be considered God's name.  The fact remains that the usage of the definite article with "elohim" is common, but not consistently the same, and it is also paired with verbs and adjectives which are either plural (for other gods) or singular (for the true God).

In Genesis 6:2, the numerical usage is ambiguous, as no verb or adjective is associated with "ha-elohim," which itself is part of a construct chain.  The word "sons" in the Hebrew is in *construct state,* which links it to the following noun in a genitive relationship.

The article "ha" before "elohim" in this verse is grammatically needed to make the entire construct chain definite, since "elohim" is not being used as a name.  With the article, the translation of that phrase should be: "**the** sons of God."  Without the article, it would be: "sons of God."  Notice that the article, in English, gets placed *at the beginning* of the construct sequence.

Comment: i thought that having an art in the position you placed it in, is just something that is necessary in English and that's why we insert them in our translations. Don't you think that it is a big jump to somehow attribute the art. connected to Elohim, with sons?

Comment: @ThatwemaybethepraiseofHisglory This is not a jump.  This is normal Hebrew grammar.  In a construct chain, if the _last_ word of the chain is definite, the _whole chain_ is made definite.  This is a very common grammatical form in Hebrew.  English grammar is not the same as Hebrew grammar, so the article must be repositioned during translation.

Comment: i think the art is there to show us who he is talking about specific, just like when it is used for "the" Adam (the holder of firstborn inheritance, the son of Adam, the seed of the woman, not the image bearers, not the beasts like serpent seed of darkness), apart from humanity.

Comment: got any other construction examples that are the same?

Comment: For another example, here is a three-word construct chain in Genesis 40:3: "in house [of] captain [of] the guard" --> "in **the** house of **the** captain of **the** guard."  Notice that only the last word has the article in Hebrew, but every word of the chain is translated as definite, having the article in English.  This is correct.  Names are automatically definite in Hebrew, so you will not find an article in the case of a construct chain ending in a name, e.g. "sons of Israel."  This is why "elohim" cannot be considered a name in Genesis 6:2.

Answer (score -1):

Does the definite article before Elohim refer to other spiritual entities?

No.

Most often Elohim refers to the true God. But sometimes it refers to other entities. The definite article has nothing to do with true God or other entities! It is the grammar or context that determines it.

True Elohim with Definite Article

> “For thus says Yahweh who created the heavens – *He is God* (Hu
> Ha Elohim) who formed the earth and made it. He has not established it in vain, who did create it to be inhabited, who formed it. I am
> Yahweh and there is no other” (Isaiah 45:18; Interlinear Bible Hub).

Nobody can say that Isaiah 45:18 is talking about “other spiritual entities”. It talks about the One true God. In fact, it is Yahweh who is speaking here.

[“Hu HaElohim” cannot be translated into English as “*the* He is God”! Literally, it has to be “He is the God”, but this is not proper in English].

Yet we see the definite article “Ha” together with Elohim; HaElohim, the true God.

Other elohim without Definite Article

> “You shall not have any other gods (elohim) before Me” (Exo 20:3).

Surely, other gods are not true God. Yet the word elohim to refer to them is without the definite article.

*Conclusion*

So, it is clear, the definite article can not be used to identify the true God or “other entities”.

True Elohim Uses Plural Verb.

Mostly, the true God Elohim uses singular verb. But there are a few occasions when the Scripture uses plural verb with true God.

Abraham tells Abimelech:

> “And it happened when God (Elohim) made me wander (“hithu” is plural)
> from my father’s house……” (Gen 20:13).

Adam Clarke commentary:-

> “Here the word אלהים Elohim is used with a plural verb, (התעו
> hithu, caused me to wander), which is not very usual in the Hebrew
> language, as this plural noun is generally joined with verbs in the
> singular number”.

[There are more instances like this. I think one will suffice here].

Genesis 6:2 talks about the True God

Genesis 6th chapter is a continuation of the 4th chapter. Chapter 5 is just an inset in between. The story continues from chapter 4 into chapter 6.

The last verse in chapter 4 says:

> “And a son was also born to Seth, and he called his name, Enos. Then
> it was begun to call on the name of Yahweh.”

There is a marginal reading here that says:

> “Then began men to call themselves by the name Yahweh” (various
> commentaries).

And how did they call themselves?

“Sons of God”.

This is similar to “people of God”, “prophets of God”, “saints of God”, “the Church of God” etc.

This was the very first group of people who followed the true God in history under the leadership of Seth. But soon, as usual, they faltered when they married beautiful women from the *unbelievers’ camp* (Gen 6:2).

It is then God said:

> “My Spirit shall not always strive with man” (verse 3).

So Genesis 6:2 is not the “sons of the gods”.

Comment: Why are you yelling?